# Converting worlds making no progress

Tags: terraria-console

I recently booted up Terraria Xbox One edition for the first time in quite a while, only to be met with a loading screen. This first said “converting characters”, but is now “converting worlds”.

The progress bar has been at 50% for over an hour now, and no more progress has been made. I’m afraid to restart the Xbox, in case data is corrupted, but I don’t know what else I could do in this situation.

So why has it been stuck without progress for so long? And will it eventually complete, or is it probable that something’s gone wrong and it will never finish converting the worlds without restarting? Will restarting now corrupt my save data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this happens when your account didn't have a world save pre- patch 1.3. So basically the game is trying to convert an older save to a new save but there's no old save for it to convert it from.

There is a way that you might be able to fix this, but you need another controller and another account that has either never played the game or an account that has had a save pre 1.3.

Steps are as follow (only do this if your save is uploaded to the cloud otherwise you'll lose the progress)

- Manage game (press start on Terraria)
- Go down to Saved Data -> Delete all, this will delete the local save
- Log out of the primary account, log in to the new account, launch the game and create a character + world
- Load into the world, press A on the other controller and pick your primary account
- You should load into the game, once fully loaded press save & exit.
- Close the game, sign out of secondary account and go back to your primary and hopefully everything's fixed.

If you can't try this then I have a feeling you need to completely restart.

Comment: Thank you, I won’t be able to do this unfortunately. How do I reset the game? Do I just understand uninstall and the reinstall it?

Comment: Because you're unable to even get to the main menu you will probably need to reinstall the game. Normally when you start the game there's an option to select a character (you can have multiple) and a world (you can have multiple).